# Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes

Tags: python, proxy, httprequest, python-requests

I want to set proxy in requests and get content of url source:

```
privoxy = 'localhost:8118'
proxy_dict = {'http':privoxy, 'https':privoxy, 'ftp':privoxy, 'ssl':privoxy}
content = session.get(url=url, proxies=proxy_dict).content
```

The following error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 305, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 206, in get_connection
    except_on_missing_scheme(proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 636, in except_on_missing_scheme
    raise MissingSchema('Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.')
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [*scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) to `http`, in your case:

```
privoxy = 'http://localhost:8118'
```

(It can be others of course, like 'https', 'ftp', etc.)

More from [Requests docs for Proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies):

> Note that proxy URLs must include the scheme.